# TMS tile source in routeme/mapbox

Tags: mapbox, route-me

Using the MapBox iOS SDK (routeme) is it possible to point to an offline TMS directory structure of tiles?

I know that I can point to an online TMS source like OpenStreetMap but I would like to just store a TMS directory structure on the device for offline use.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't out of the box, but you can create your own `RMTileSource` to easily do this. You want to go straight up to `RMTileSource` as opposed to modeling after something like `RMOpenStreetMapSource` since this is a subclass of the general web tile handling class.